# How to cluster U.S. zipcodes geographically with the constraint that clusters have approximately equal population?

Tags: clustering

I am familiar with k-means but don't know how this additional constraint could be worked into the algorithm. Any insight into a k-means modification or a different algorithm is appreciated.

Comment: can you give an example of your data set? Are they geographic points for each zip code? can you show anything you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes, the data set (which I haven't acquired yet) would be an sqlite database with the following schema: CREATE TABLE zips (

zip TEXT,
longitude NUMERIC,
latitude NUMERIC,
population INTEGER
);

Answer (score 0):

"Equal size" or "equal population" *contradicts* the idea of clustering.

For example, you will likely have to put Hawaii together with Alaska. They are not similar, but maybe the best way to satisfy the size requirements.

Rather than clustering (which is about discovering *structural patterns*) you should rather treat this as an optimization problem. Specify your quality criterion, then have a solver search for a good solution.

Comment: The difficulty is that most generic "solvers" will have a hard time with this problem.  Specialized techniques, such as Spatial Simulated Annealing, tend to work much better.